# Help creating basic validation rule on PickList Value

Tags: validation

I need some help creating a basic validation rule

Aim – If field name “Client_Business_Type” contains “pension” then field name “Pension_Fund_Type” is mandatory

Field Label : Type of money
Field Name : Client_Business_Type
Api : Client_Business_Type__c
Data type : Picklist

Field Label : Pension Fund Type
Field Name : Pension_Fund_Type
Api : Pension_Fund_Type__c
Data type : Picklist

I have currently tried following validation rule. which works fine. However, instead of listing each pension from within the picklist. **Is there anyway i can do a wildcard search for the word pension in the picklist value**?

If I add more picklist values that contain the word 'Pension', I don't want to have to adjust the validation rule.  Is there any way to find any picklist value that contains the word 'Pension'?

```
ISPICKVAL( Client_Business_Type__c , "Pension Fund - Public sector") && ISPICKVAL( Pension_Fund_Type__c, "" )
```

Comment: Why dont you just follow the examples provided by SFDC and try create your validation rule.

If you face any problem then post it here. 

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_useful_field_validation_formulas.htm

Comment: Have you tried anything so far for us to build/advise on?

Comment: i have the following validation rule. which works fine. However, instead of listing each pension from within the picklist. Is there anyway i can do a wildcard search for the word pension ?

ISPICKVAL( Client_Business_Type__c , "Pension Fund - Public sector") && ISPICKVAL( Pension_Fund_Type__c, "" )

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the CONTAINS() function along with the TEXT() function.  Something like this should work for any picklist value that has the word pension in it.

```
AND(    
    CONTAINS(TEXT(Client_Business_Type__c), LOWER('pension')),
    ISBLANK(TEXT(Pension_Fund_Type__c)
)
```